# HttpHandler image generation and Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, httphandler

I have developed a HttpHandler which generates a dynamic image from data in a database record.

This handler is working correctly if I use it in a regular web page or if I call it directly in the address bar. But I want to use it in a report viewer using Reporting Services.  However when I do this, the picture is not printed (the html source is : ).

If I use a regular web page instead of my handler, it works correctly.

What can I do to include an image generated by a HttpHandler in Reporting Services?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  We were not setting the correct response header from the handler.  Setting the response header...

```
Content-type: image/jpeg
```

Fixed the issue